# Which is correct "The house is (being sold | selling)"?

Tags: passive-voice, present-continuous

Will it be correct if I would say "This house is selling" meaning that someone is selling the house? Or I should only say "The house is being sold" to be understood right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The house is being sold.

means the owners have put a single house up for sale.

> The house is selling.

can be said to meaning there is keen interest by several buyers in the house.

It can also be used in the plural to mean houses *in general*

> *(The)* house*s* *are* *selling*.

Comment: That said, to say "The house is selling" in isolation sounds rather odd to this US English speaker, and I wouldn't ever use it to mean "Someone is selling the house."  I would expect to hear it in a context like "The house is selling *for two million dollars.*"

Comment: It might be used by a realtor in answer to the question by the seller "How's it going?" that there is interest in the house "The house is selling." meaning people have been coming by for the open house, asking questions and showing interest. Maybe it's more a New Yorker way of expressing it.